# Is my boss trying to make me resign?

Tags: termination

I'm a VP (technical) at a fairly well known company in its field. I've been there for about 2-1/2 years now.

I've had good performance appraisals, and most recently (December) was rated "4 - Exceeds Expectations". I have done a lot of good for the company (other peoples' opinions, not mine. Only saying this because it might be relevant as will be evident when done reading).

The situation:

- I'm very good at what I do (many people including boss tell me this)
- I have very limited social skills - not Dustin Hoffman in Rain Man, but socially "not at all adept" is how I'd put it.
- In the last month we've encountered a problem with a cloud platform we built. It's become clear that some infrastructure configuration is flawed (wasn't tested by the responsible team - who reports to one of my peers, not me).
- The internal customer business-unit is highly political and is using the situation to repeatedly ding my boss (CxO - Can't give away too much).

In the last 2 weeks, my boss has put incredibly tight constraints on me. Example: before doing any tests to diagnose/prove the root cause (it's my specialty), I have to ask one of my peers for approval.

Today I was instructed to stop all testing until a meeting about this platform within the next week. I'm bewildered as to what could be the reason for clipping the wings of an acknowledged expert in this field and freezing everything for 2 days? Any well designed test will improve knowledge and give more confidence in the diagnosis - but CxO is prohibiting me doing any testing at all.

Having given me great reviews, paying me well, and recently himself rating me "4 - Exceeds", might he have painted himself into a corner and thus make firing me very complicated?

**May be relevant**: I've self-identified as having a disability (gave no detail, but it's Asperger's and yes I know DSM-V has removed this). I (unadvisedly ???) told him about 6-8 months ago that I have AS and I am over 40.

**Question**: Is he trying to make me resign, or is this just extreme case of control-freakyness?

I think this would be tricky for even a neurotypical person, but I am totally lost; being good at my job is all I know; I have zero political IQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's so much context missing here that could tip this one way or another. That's not your fault; if you have a diagnosis and aren't 'socially adept' - then you are probably going to miss it.

However this section is what I'm going to focus on:

> In the last 2 weeks, my boss has put incredibly tight constraints on me. Example: before doing any tests to diagnose/prove the root cause (it's my specialty), I have to ask one of my peers for approval.
>
> Today I was instructed to stop all testing until a meeting about this
> platform within the next week. I'm bewildered - what could be the
> reason for clipping the wings of an acknowledged expert in this field
> and freezing everything for 2 days? Any well designed test will
> improve knowledge and give more confidence in the diagnosis - but CxO
> is prohibiting me doing any testing at all.

Here's the conversation I suspect happened between your boss and the other people that are affected/angry about the current scenario:

"That worker User192127 has too much freedom and thinks he owns the company and acts like it's his personal little kingdom - you've got to rein him in and make him do what's best for the company."

I imagine your boss (if he's rated you as exceeds performance) probably tried to stick up for you - but in the end someone would have said something like:

"The buck stops with him, you need to sort him out."

And the net result is a significant restriction.

Now - to answer your question: Is your boss trying to fire you? My gut feeling is 'no'.

I say that for two reasons - I've been involved in projects where, due to circumstances, people were told explicitly 'hands off' until certain people in Management were up-to-speed and were comfortable with the changes being made. It sucks and it can really feel like you are being unfairly punished - but it happens.

Secondly - if the intent was to fire you or otherwise make you resign - then I would expect there to have been a chat with HR and some form of warning involved.

Based on my personal experience - I suspect your Boss has ordered a hands-off, because he's been asked questions he doesn't have answers for and feels that the tail is wagging the dog, not the other way around. So he orders a stop, gets the full picture from you, then incrementally restores access/rights etc. so that he feels he has proper control and oversight as to what is being done.

Answer (score 8):

We can't give a definitive answer, because there are so many unknowns here, but here is my impression;

There are political maneuvers brewing. You've been asked to hold off on work until a meeting has taken place - you're assuming that this is related to your performance, but it's quite likely that it isn't. Someone - and it isn't you - has messed up. At the moment, management don't want any testing or corrective actions taking place, and it's possible that it's because the person or contractor who did the work is going to be canned. If you test the issue and fix it, you put them in an unfortunate situation of no longer having the reasons they needed to fire someone.

The only way you'll find out what's going on is to talk to your boss about your concerns. My feeling is that you're safe; someone in your position would  have been escorted out of the premises and locked out from all servers very quickly.

Answer (score 7):

If you can't bear to wait a few more days for the official statement, telling your manager that this freeze-until-announcement is making you uncomfortable and asking if you've done anything wrong will not do any harm.

It sounds more like a general freeze while they decide how to address a major issue (either in the product or in the business).

Comment: Indeed, and if it's a business-critical problem  and there are few experts in the company, a complete freeze may well be a panic response: "don't break anything else until we've figured this out"